# Submit form when contents of MVC3 Html.TextBoxFor changes

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-ajax

This should be fairly easy but I've tried a few things with no luck.

I have a series of `Html.TextBoxFor` fields on a page, each inside their own `Ajax.BeginRouteForm`.  Next to each box I have a submit button, and this, when clicked, performs the Ajax update as desired.

I'd like to automate this so that when the user changes a value in a field (the `onchange` event) the form is submitted the same way it currently using using the submit button.

I tried using the htmlattributes to assign a JavaScript function to the `onchange` event (as shown below) and this causes the form to submit, but it redirects the page instead of working in the ajax fashion (as opposed to clicking the submit button which works correctly).

```
@(Html.TextBoxFor(model => answer.Value, new { onchange = "document.forms[" + answer.AnswerID + "].submit()" }));
```

(fortunately my `answer.AnswerID` is numeric and matches up with the numeric position of the appropriate form in the forms collection; I was referencing them by name but Razor (or something) was htmlencoding my JavaScript code...)

My only guess is that I'm breaking something by attaching code directly to the `onchange` event, but I'm at a loss as to the "right" way to hook into that event chain.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use JQuery, it's very simple to do:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Comment: Please feel free to elaborate :)

Answer (score 0):

Calling `submit()` on a form will ignore any `submit` event handlers, [as seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/RvshT/). You can either

1. [call the event handler directly](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/RvshT/1/), or
2. [call `click()` on the submit button for the form](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/RvshT/2/).

The former works best if you use `onsubmit` and return `false` instead of using the `event` argument to the callback, because otherwise you need to pass another messy object or something.